# SQL Having, Order BY. Вывести всех пользователей из БД расходы которые превышают 1000$ за последние 30 дней

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица продукты:
`Products` структура: 
`id, user_id, product_price`

Вопрос: Как мне вывести пользователей которые превышают 1000$ за последние 30 дней? (последний 30 дней для каждого пльзователя)

Запрос выводит всех пользователей которые прев. 1000, но я не могу туда лимит поставить на 30

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    SUM(product_price)
FROM products
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(product_price) >= 1000
```

---

```
SELECT t.user_id,
  SUM(t.product_price) 
FROM (SELECT 
        p.user_id, 
        p.product_price
      FROM products p
        ORDER BY p.id DESC LIMIT 30) t
  GROUP BY t.user_id
    HAVING SUM(t.product_price) >= 1000;
```

не помогло

Comment: Это невозможно, потому что у вас в таблице нет никаких полей с датой и 30 дней отсчитывать не от чего

Comment: @Mike да, правильно. Я ступил в мыслях считая их днями

Comment: Тогда поправьте вопрос, что бы было понятно, что же вам на самом деле нужно

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```
SELECT
  p.user_id,
  SUM(p.product_price) OVER(PARTITION BY p.user_id)
FROM products AS p
  WHERE p.product_price >= 1000;
```

а вот насчет того как Вы хотите получить данные за последние 30 дней я не понял, в таблице об этом ни слова

Как то так можно сделать по id, date:

```
SELECT
  p.user_id,
  SUM(p.product_price) OVER(PARTITION BY p.date)
FROM products AS p
  WHERE p.product_price >= 1000
  GROUP BY p.user_id;
```

Без оконных функций:

```
SELECT
  p.user_id,
  SUM(p.product_price)
FROM products AS p
  WHERE p.product_price >= 1000
  GROUP BY p.user_id, p.date /*Здесь нужно обработать дату для более корректных результатов*/;
```

Comment: где синтаксическая ошибка?

Comment: там все норм...

Comment: там говорится что, версия вашего сервера MySQL это не поддерживает

Comment: тогда получается MySQL с оконными функциями беда

Comment: В MySQL оконных функций нет в принципе

Comment: @MIke, я уже понял

Comment: @Mike, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html

Comment: @MaxU Судя по текущей распространенности 8 версии она будет актуальна года через 2. И то при условии, что percona свои патчи на нее поставит

Answer (score 1):

Для начала надо добавить в таблицу столбец с типом `datetime`,

Далее изменить запрос примерно на такой

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    SUM(product_price)
FROM products
WHERE date > DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING SUM(product_price) >= 1000
LIMIT 12
```

Comment: а если я с хочу получить за последние 30 дней предыдущего месяца, то этот запрос вряд ли сработает, проблема в дизайне самой таблицы

Comment: @Yaroslav в вопросе было четко указано что надо данные за последний месяц причем 2 раза. в случае если надо данные за другой период то надо использовать *BETWEEN*  - `WHERE date BETWEEN '1996-07-01' AND '1996-07-31'`

Comment: я бы так не делал

Comment: Друзя, надо вытаскивать пользователей которые превышают 1000, 1000 это максимальный расход, больше 1000$ в месяц должны налог платить за это. Поле с датой есть но я не хочу полбзоваться этим мне надо с айди решать эту проблему

Comment: надо правильно группировать.

Comment: @Azad, по id это не правильно.

Comment: он подходит, но лучше писать универсально

Comment: по дате  и юзерах